# Did PHP date interval format come from another programming language?

Tags: php, date, datetime

Does anyone know if PHP date interval format such as **P2Y4DT6H8M** came from another language?

I am trying to determine if PHP date interval formatting can be used by multiple languages.

More examples of DateInterval formats can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php

Comment: It's coming from ISO8601 specification.

Comment: @Rayhan Muktader: try the search functions or google...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as per [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php), it's [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso8601#Durations).